# Next.js: <Link> pre-fetch to another domain

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, vercel

My Next.js app is made up of many micro front-ends, but it's all displayed under one domain using [Next.js rewrites](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/rewrites).

So for example:

1. Blog project deploys to `https://my-blog-project.vercel.app`, but is then accessed via `https://my-project.vercel.app/blog`.
2. Store project deploys to `https://my-store-project.vercel.app`, but is then accessed via `https://my-project.vercel.app/store`.

I do this by adding rewrites to a "root" projects of source. So for example:

```
const nextConfig = {
  rewrites: () => [
    // this will send requests to /blog to the blog project
    {
      source: "/blog/:match*",
      destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BLOG_URL}/blog/:match*`,
    },
    // this will send requests to /store to the store project
    {
      source: "/store/:match*",
      destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORE_URL}/store/:match*`,
    },
  ],
};
```

This works surprisingly well and it's allowed me to keep complexity to a minimum for each project.

The one issue I'm having is that Next.js' `<Link>` [component prefetches content from my Next.js pages to improve loading time](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/link#prefetch). It's a great feature which really improves user experience.

Unfortunately this feature does not work with my setup, since the root project attempts to prefetch this JSON from its own domain:

```
GET: https://my-project.vercel.app/_next/data/1rNa7mdg2z-3PmPwk8pWl/blog/a-random-blog

// instead of

GET: https://my-blog-project.vercel.app/_next/data/1rNa7mdg2z-3PmPwk8pWl/blog/a-random-blog
```

I initially thought I'd be able to add a new rewrite to fix this:

```
const nextConfig = {
  rewrites: () => [
    // rewrite to the correct domain
    {
      source: `/_next/data/:release/blog/:path*`,
      destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BLOG_URL}/_next/data/:release/blog/:path*`,
    },
    // this will send requests to /blog to the blog project
    {
      source: "/blog/:match*",
      destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BLOG_URL}/blog/:match*`,
    },
    // this will send requests to /store to the store project
    {
      source: "/store/:match*",
      destination: `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STORE_URL}/store/:match*`,
    },
  ],
};
```

But Next.js is fully ignoring this rewrite.

I know I can fully disable prefetch on `<Link>`, but as I mentioned it's a good feature so I'd like to have it working.

Any ideas if or how I can work around this?